# Time Measurement Unit in CPLEX

Tags: cplex, ilog, time-measurement

In IBM ILOG CPLEX model I use "MyCplex.getCplexTime()" for measuring the time but it gives output as "time:2338551.031". I couldn`t figure out the unit of it. Is there any code to get time in seconds?

Answer (score 0):

let me quote CPLEX documentation:

> To measure time spent between a starting point and ending point of an
> operation, take the time stamp at the starting point; take the time
> stamp at the ending point; subtract the starting time stamp from the
> ending time stamp to get elapsed time in seconds.
>
> This computation measures either wall clock time (also known as real
> time) or CPU time, depending on the setting of the clock type
> parameter ClockType.
>
> The absolute value of the time stamp is not meaningful.